# Java Streams: filtering with 2 objects

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have the problem that I have a collection of roads connecting two places & I want to find all connections from A to B when there is no direct connection, so the trip would go from A to X (maybe even to Y) to B.
However, when I already know that there is no direct connection, I don't now how to filter as I think I would need more than 1 object.

```
routes = allroutes
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getStart() == start)
    .filter(p,x -> p.getEnd() == x.getStart())
    .filter(x -> x.getEnd() ==  end)
```

and the filter(p,x....) is the thing that doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve it differently.
Of course, all streams, lists etc have been initialized correctly before.

Comment: First you need to find the path from A to B, which as you said can have many intermediate points, so there can be a very high count of objects. As such, streams are not the right tool for what you're doing. Re-think what you're trying to accomplish. --- The act of finding a path (route) is known as "[graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)", in case you want to do some *research* on the subject.

Comment: Well there can be a easy solution and a difficult one, depending upon the size of collection. Better choice is to go with Graph data structure. Kindly give some sample data at least to try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need two values from the list at the same time here, I am not sure of a way to achieve this using streams. (Others may comment.) However, since I found the problem interesting, I quickly tried it out on a simple Java class. I have used a simple `for..each` loop rather than Java streams.

```
public class RouteFinder{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        List<Route> allroutes = new ArrayList<>();
        populateData( allroutes );

        findIndirectBetween( allroutes, "A", "B" ).forEach( System.out::println );
    }

    private static List<Route> findIndirectBetween( List<Route> allroutes, String start, String end ){
        List<Route> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        if( start.equals( end ) ) return selected;

        for( Route route : allroutes ) {
            List<String> rStops = route.getStops();
            if( !rStops.contains( start ) || !rStops.contains( end ) ) continue;

            int startIndex = rStops.indexOf( start );
            int endIndex = rStops.indexOf( end );
            if( startIndex != endIndex + 1 && startIndex != endIndex -1 ) selected.add( route );
        }

        return selected;
    }

    private static void populateData( List<Route> routes ) {
        routes.add( Route.of( "1", "A", "H", "C", "B" ) );
        routes.add( Route.of( "2", "A", "B" ) );
        routes.add( Route.of( "3", "C", "K", "L", "Z" ) );
        routes.add( Route.of( "4", "C", "L", "Z" ) );
        routes.add( Route.of( "5", "C", "B", "Z", "A" ) );
    }

    private static class Route{
        private String routeNumber;

        private List<String> stops = new ArrayList<>();

        public Route( String routeNumber, List<String> stops) {
            super();
            this.routeNumber = routeNumber;
            this.stops = stops;
        }

        public static Route of( String number, String... stops ) {
            List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();
            if( stops != null ) for( String s : stops ) ss.add( s );

            return new Route( number, ss );
        }

        public String getStart() {
            if( this.stops != null && this.stops.size() > 0 ) return this.stops.get( 0 );
            return "";
        }

        public String getEnd() {
            if( this.stops != null && this.stops.size() > 0 ) return this.stops.get( this.stops.size() - 1 );
            return "";
        }

        public List<String> getStops(){
            return this.stops;
        }

        public String getRouteNumber(){
            return routeNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "routeNumber=" + routeNumber + ", stops=" + stops;
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

On second thoughts, there is a way to do it using streams, I think.

```
private static List<Route> findIndirectBetweenUsingStreams( List<Route> allroutes, String start, String end ){
    return allroutes.stream()
            .filter( r -> r.getStops().contains( start ) ) //Retain routes which have "start"ing point
            .filter( r -> r.getStops().contains( end ) ) //Retain routes which have "end" point
            .collect( ArrayList::new, ( newRouteList, r ) -> {
                List<String> rStops = r.getStops();
                int startIndex = rStops.indexOf( start );
                int endIndex = rStops.indexOf( end );
                if( startIndex != endIndex + 1 && startIndex != endIndex -1 ) newRouteList.add( r );
            },
                ( newRouteList, r ) -> {} );
}
```

This code uses the model `Route` and the basic code in the class I pasted above. This method can be called instead of `findIndirectBetween()`.